# Search by selector by class name and style property JS

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I am trying to return the desired element by its unique properties. To do this, I need to use something like this code. I have a mistake in it, how do I make this entry correct?

```
document.querySelector('div[class="className" style*="text-decoration:line-through"]')
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the proper class syntax `div.className`?

Comment: @VLAZ, That was one of my mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate the attribute selectors:

```
document.querySelector('div[class="className"][style*="text-decoration:line-through"]');
```

Also note that as you're using a class to target the elements, use a class selector for better performance:

```
document.querySelector('div.className[style*="text-decoration:line-through"]');
```

Lastly, your `style` selector is incredibly brittle, and very easily broken. For example, if someone validly uses `text-decoration: line-through` then it will not be matched. I would strongly suggest you use a class to apply the style and select the element.

Comment: Awesome. It works. The text with the line was a property of the element, not of the class, and now there is no problem with the crossed-out text. Now I am faced with difficulties with the choice of color. I call this entry and get null. Maybe because the color is set in the css properties?

`document.querySelector('.className[style*="color: #0070ff"]');`

Comment: 'Maybe because the color is set in the css properties' yes that would be a problem. For the attribute selector to work the attribute needs to be in the HTML. If you want to select via a CSS style, you can use `filter()` instead.